# Editing start page in Elm

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, sass, elm

This is my first time working with Elm.
If not the solution, could you suggest a resource that would help me solve such a problem ?
The code given below is the start page for a website, from which I need to remove a few things    -->

1. A logo in the top left of the page (the part with `Ad` in the code)
2. The whole footer (2 other logos and a version string).

I tried just removing the code which deals with this, but it started returning errors about it being `Html Global.Msg` and there being structural errors in the code. Errors about `type annotation :` and that this is not a function.

This is my first time working with `Elm`, so I am unable to understand anything at all.
I couldn't get the exact errors also as I am asking this question hours after getting them and using the original instead.
Thanks anyways ;)

```
view : Shared -> Model -> List (Html Global.Msg)
view shared model =
    let
        r =
            model.route

        yum-cheeseAd { baseUrl } =
            Html.blankA
                [ HtmlA.href baseUrl, HtmlA.id "yum-cheese-ad", Strings.YumCheeseWhereToGet |> Lang.title shared ]
                [ Html.div []
                    [ Icon.boxOpen |> Icon.viewIcon
                    , Html.span [] [ Strings.YumCheese |> Lang.string shared |> Html.text ]
                    ]
                ]
    in
    [ Html.div [ HtmlA.class "page start" ]
        [ overlay shared model.overlay
        , Html.header [ HtmlA.class "title-card" ]
            [ Html.h1 [] [ Html.div [ HtmlA.class "card-slicer" ] [ Call.viewUnknown shared [] ] ]
            , Html.div [ HtmlA.class "subtitle" ]
                [ Html.div [ HtmlA.class "card-slicer" ]
                    [ Response.view shared Configure.fake Card.Front [] (subtitleCard shared)
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        , Card.view []
            [ Tabs.view shared
                { selected = r.section
                , change = \s -> Route.Start { r | section = s } |> Global.ChangePage
                , ids = NeList New [ Join model.gameCode, Find, About ]
                , tab = tabFor
                , equals = sectionsMatch
                }
            , sectionContent shared model
            ]
        , Html.footer [ HtmlA.class "version-info" ]
            [ Html.div [ HtmlA.class "logos" ]
                [ Html.blankA
                    [ HtmlA.class "logo"
                    , Strings.Project |> Lang.title shared
                    , HtmlA.href "https://something.com/"
                    ]
                    [ Icon.viewStyled [ Strings.LogoDescription |> Lang.alt shared ] Icon.YumCheese ]
                , Html.blankA
                    [ HtmlA.class "logo"
                    , Strings.DevelopedBy |> Lang.title shared
                    , HtmlA.href "https://www.qazwsx.com/"
                    ]
                    [ Icon.viewStyled [ Strings.LogoDescription |> Lang.alt shared ] Icon.rereadGames ]
                ]
            , Html.p [ HtmlA.class "version" ]
                [ Html.text "\""
                , Strings.YumCheese |> Lang.html shared
                , Html.text "\" "
                , Strings.Version { versionNumber = Version.version } |> Lang.html shared
                ]
            ]
        ]
    , shared.sources.yumcheese |> Maybe.map yumcheeseAd |> Maybe.withDefault Html.nothing
    ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this:

```
view : Shared -> Model -> List (Html Global.Msg)
view shared model =
    let
        r =
            model.route
    in
    [ Html.div [ HtmlA.class "page start" ]
        [ overlay shared model.overlay
        , Html.header [ HtmlA.class "title-card" ]
            [ Html.h1 [] [ Html.div [ HtmlA.class "card-slicer" ] [ Call.viewUnknown shared [] ] ]
            , Html.div [ HtmlA.class "subtitle" ]
                [ Html.div [ HtmlA.class "card-slicer" ]
                    [ Response.view shared Configure.fake Card.Front [] (subtitleCard shared)
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        , Card.view []
            [ Tabs.view shared
                { selected = r.section
                , change = \s -> Route.Start { r | section = s } |> Global.ChangePage
                , ids = NeList New [ Join model.gameCode, Find, About ]
                , tab = tabFor
                , equals = sectionsMatch
                }
            , sectionContent shared model
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

I removed the footer and the ad. Your error sounds like a syntax error. I suspect you went wrong by messing up the nested lists when you deleted stuff.

If this doesn't fix your problem, I would suggest:

1. Putting the complete error message in your question.
2. Reading the Elm [official guide](https://guide.elm-lang.org/) if you haven't already. It won't take too long and will help with understanding the language.
3. Constructing a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This is what I do when stuck. Often you will find the solution while constructing it.